# Jquery table undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

In my MVC project I have implemented JQuery datatables to retrieve data.I am using 1.9.4 jquery.dataTables.js. I have three filters to restrict the output in the table. Two of which works perfectly. However on the third option which suppose to show all records I receive "Undefined" pop up alert. I tried both in IE and Google chrome.

[image]

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Call log";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/datatables/JS/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/datatables/JS/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/json2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/json2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        GetUsers(1);
        $('#select-filter').change(function () {
            GetUsers($(this).val());
        });
    });
function GetUsers(filter) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/GetAllUsers',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify({ filter: filter }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (idata) {
                DisplayDataTables(idata.aaData);
                return;
            },
            error: function (idata) {
                alert(idata.msg);
            }
        });
    }

    function DisplayDataTables(aDataSet) {
        $('#divBRUsers').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="tbl-users"></table>');
        $('#tbl-users').DataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aaData": aDataSet,
            "aoColumns": [
                 {
                     "sTitle": "Customer ID",
                     "sClass": "center",
                     "sName": "Employee ID",
                     "fnRender": function (oObj) {
                         return '<a href="/home/logdetails?cifid=' + oObj.aData[0] + '" title="' + oObj.aData[0] + '">' + oObj.aData[0] + '</a>';
                     }
                 },
                { "sTitle": "Customer Name", "sClass": "left" },
                { "sTitle": "Customer Address", "sClass": "left" },
                { "sTitle": "Customer City", "sClass": "left" },
                { "sTitle": "Contacted Before", "sClass": "left" }
                //{ "sTitle": "Campaign Name", "sClass": "center" }
            ]
        });
    }
</script>
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="div-add-campaign-form">
        Filter <select class="dtSearch" id="select-filter">
            <option value="1">Assigned to me</option>
            <option value="2">Associated with my branch</option>
            <option value="3">View all</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="divBRUsers">
        Please wait, loading data...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Andreas I updated the post let me know if this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, consider the following object for your jquery dataTable instantiation:

```
var conf = {
   columnDefs : [ { className : '...' }, targets : { 3, 6, 7} ],
   columns: [
     [ title : 'product id' ],
     [ title : 'product name' ]
   ],
   data : [
     [ 23, "Cellular" ] // nested array, pay attention to the number of values added, 2 values, by order: productId, productName
   ],
   order: [[0,'desc']], // first column set to desc, add a new value in the array to apply multi-order, values order matters!!
   destroy : !0,
   pageLength : 10,
   paging : !0,  // full number pagination is set as default
   responsive : !0,
   bSort : !0,
   bSortable : !0,
   bFilter : !1,
   autoWidth : !1
};
```

As you can see, simply the object defines a table for apparently 2 columns 'productId', 'productName'; Adjust that to fit your case where it's gonna be a matter of adding values to the columns array, any extra config you wanna add to the columns you will have to add it to the columnDefs (short for columnDefinitions).

Remember, you will keep receiving errors similar to the one reported if the set of data doesn't match the columns. Make sure each nested array in the data array have the same number of values as for the columns, read the comments for more details. if for any reason, your data doesn't match that order, you gonna have to change that order manually, force empty values with '-' or 'n/a' values so all nested arrays have the same logic of values.

I hope this helps. 
Good luck.